# setting viewbag value and text to same field

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Usually when using viewbags for dropdown lists they contain an id column and value column but for a title one i had to change it as it comes from a third party application and now it isn't working as before.  It renders the drop down back but when i hit the back button and use session variable to re-populate the form the value isn't being set for this, for gender it works fine.

```
public ActionResult _NewEmpDetails()
{
    var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;
    ViewBag.NameTitle = new SelectList(db.vwInproTitle.ToList(), "Title", "Title");
    ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(db.vwLkUpGender.ToList(), "GenderID", "Gender");
    Employee Employee = sessionValues.Employee;
    return PartialView("_NewEmpDetails", Employee);
}
```

view

```
<div style="display: table-cell;" class="tCell">
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) </div>
    <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NameTitle, "Please select a title", new { @class = "dropdown", id = "txtTitle" })</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
</div>
```

The for gender it is setup the same, the only difference is that for gender it has a value and text column.

When i load the employee for the drop down box values are there, but if i complete the form and move onto the next one, then hit back all the other values are populated except title.  If i submit the form the title value IS stored so i know that it isn't an issue of the value being lost.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is selected in your title dropdown, then one of the following is at play:

1. `Model.Title` is blank coming into the view.
2. `Model.Title` *has* a value, but it doesn't match any of the option values.
3. You have something in `ModelState` that is taking precedence (`ViewBag.Title`, `ViewData["Title"]` or `Request["Title"]` is set to something that doesn't match any of the option values.)